# What is the difference between . and * in "git add"?

Tags: git

while in `git add` command, I use `.` and `*` to add all the files in the working directory.

What is the difference between them?

Comment: If you really want to see the difference without changing anything try `git add -nv` to do a dry run with the verbose option ON.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Neither of these are `git` concepts:

`.` is a representation of the *current working directory*. So if you say, for example, `git add .`, you really mean "git, please add the current working directory to the staging area for my current change". Most other commands treat `.` the same way: `cd .` will move you nowhere.

`*`, on the other hand, is a *shell glob*. This particular glob is exapanded to "all files". So when you say `git add *`, what first happens is that your shell (the program you're typing commands into) expands it to be every file and directory in your current location, then `git` gets **that** list. So the `git` command doesn't even see the `*` at all - it just sees that you wanted to `add` everything in your current working directory.

The net effect is basically the same: everything in the working directory gets added. The way it happens, though, is totally different. `git add .` is probably what you wanted to do - what it does under the hood is nearer to your intent.

Comment: using "git add \*" might results in a problem if you have a huge number of files. It could happen, that "\*" is expended in a very large string and the length of this string might exceed the shell buffer for commands. Thus, the command might be truncated (most likely cutting a file name). Hence, the command could fail if you use "*".